# Auto-zooming bootstrap elements in browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, cross-browser, zooming

I created a web app that uses bootstrap elements. When I pushed to production, I notice that on some browsers (ie: Safari, Firefox) my webpage auto zooms so that the elements appear larger than when I was designing them in my local environment (looks fine in Chrome).

**Safari:**

[image: screenshot]

**After fixing zoom manually:**

[image: screenshot]

**Code:** [on my github](https://github.com/fhcheng/fhcheng.github.io)

Could someone help point me to the right direction? If I decrease the browser zoom manually on other browsers, my webpage looks fine. I would like to find a solution on my end that does not require one to manually change the zoom %.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if I understand you correctly you would like to zoom out your content in Safari and Firefox. This page has something that I think may interest you. Fiddle around with it. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Basically **scale()** affects the size of the element. This also applies to the font-size, padding, height, and width of an element, too. It’s also a a shorthand function for the scaleX and scaleY functions.